# Failing AJAX requests

Tags: android, ajax, angularjs, cordova, android-browser

I have a Cordova, Angular-based mobile application. When testing it on a poor EDGE connection on Android 4.3 stock browser, sometimes my http request fails (timeout or just bad signal I don't know).
That's ok, I catch the error and display error message. The problem is that all subsequent requests fail too even though the connection is ok now.
I need to restart the app to be able to make successful requests again.

This problem doesn't occur when I manually turn off the mobile connection (error msg cought) and then turn it on (request succeeds).

Has anybody seen this problem too?